# Mixpanel integration

Tags: android, eclipse, analytics, mixpanel

I'm trying to integrate Mixpanel in my app , I've followed their guide of using it in Eclipse :
https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/android-eclipse/
I've imported the google play services library, and then the mix panel 
[image]

but I'm getting lots of errors :

```
ConnectionResult cannot be resolved to a variable   AnalyticsMessages.java  /mixpanel-android/java/com/mixpanel/android/mpmetrics      

GooglePlayServicesUtil cannot be resolved   AnalyticsMessages.java  /mixpanel-android/java/com/mixpanel/android/mpmetrics   

IntDef cannot be resolved to a type Tweaks.java /mixpanel-android/java/com/mixpanel/android/mpmetrics   

The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type IntDef Tweaks.java /mixpanel-android/java/com/mixpanel/android/mpmetrics

The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/Users/myUser/Downloads/mixpanel-android-4.6.2/src/main/bin/mixpanel-android.jar' 

The import android.support cannot be resolved   Tweaks.java /mixpanel-android/java/com/mixpanel/android/mpmetrics   

The import com.google cannot be resolved    AnalyticsMessages.java  /mixpanel-android/java/com/mixpanel/android/mpmetrics

The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add google play services library as a dependency of MixPanel and then build Mixpanel. All yours issues will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

In this fig **added jar show red mark, please you can delete reference and add once again.** hope it will help you.

[For more help you can check here](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/android-eclipse/)